# Change page source without using document.write()

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change/replace the full page source of a page using JS (this is what happens when you use document.write), but document.write() is not recommended. I've tried document.innerHTML and some others, but I can't find one that works. Is there a way to 'rewrite' the page source using JS that respects best practices? Thanks in advance! (This is my first question, so tell me if I'm doing something wrong)

**Edit: I mean change all of the page source (including head), not just the body.**

Example:
Before running JS, the page source is:
`<html><head></head><body>Hi</body></html>`

After running JS: `<html><head><title>ttl</title></head><body>Hi!!M</body></html>`

Comment: innerHTML can you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML="JavaScript";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML="Hello World!";
</script>
```

This will overwrite all the things of your html document and write Hello World!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but is there some way to change the whole document?

Comment: @HACKERALERT This will change your whole document only I have tried this

Comment: Yes, it can change the body, but I'm looking for a way to change the WHOLE document, meaning the head as well.